# Quartz.net Scheduler Trigger 4 times with difference of some miliseconds Deployed at IIS

Tags: c#, triggers, quartz.net

I Just Want To Trigger Event Only once in a Day At specific Time But it trigger 4 Times with difference of some miliseconds
Below Is My Scheduler Class

```
public class CustomerEventAssigningJobScheduler
{
    private static IScheduler _scheduler;
   
  
    public static IScheduler scheduler
    {
        get
        {
            if (_scheduler == null)
            {


                IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler().Result;
                _scheduler = scheduler;
            }
            return _scheduler;
        }
    }

    public static async Task Start()
    {

        await scheduler.Start();
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CustomerEventAssigningJob>().WithIdentity("CustomerEventAssigningJob").Build();


        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("CustomerEventAssigningJob")
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
            (s =>

                 s.OnEveryDay()
               .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(00, 10))
                 .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                 .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc)                     
            )
            .Build();



        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
}
```

I have Tried: `.EndingDailyAfterCount(1)`

But after adding it does not trigger

screen shot of log is here:

[image: logofTriggers]

Comment: This looks fine, are you sure you aren't running this code multiple times, or have multiple applications running or, anything else ?

Comment: @TheGeneral Production And Dev Applications Running on server both have same code

Comment: Like usually, I would recommend adding logging. You also seem to have a database, check how many triggers are there. Also failing trigger can cause retry immediately.

Comment: @MarkoLahma How to log how many triggers are there

Comment: There's `IReadOnlyCollection<TriggerKey>triggers = await scheduler.GetTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher<TriggerKey>.AnyGroup());`

Answer (score 0):

Please check below, as we do not need to use OnEveryDay(), as we already used WithIntervalInHours(24).
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
(s =>
s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
.StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(00, 10))
)
.Build();

Its need to check server configuration/deployment, because on local machine, its ran one time.

Comment: But What is the reason of triggering twice

Comment: I have used your code example but still it ran three times after Deploying but on local it ran once